# To whom does Jefferson refer in the "Tree of Liberty" quote?

Tags: united-states, jefferson

The famous [tree of liberty](https://www.monticello.org/site/research-and-collections/tree-liberty-quotation) quote, in full reads:

> God forbid we should ever be 20 years without such a rebellion. The people cannot be all, & always well informed. The part which is wrong will be discontented in proportion to the importance of the facts they misconceive. If they remain quiet under such misconceptions it is a lethargy, the forerunner of death to the public liberty.  We have had 13 states independent 11 years. There has been one rebellion. That comes to one rebellion in a century & a half for each state. What country before ever existed a century & a half without a rebellion? & what country can preserve it's liberties if their rulers are not warned from time to time that their people preserve the spirit of resistance? **Let them take arms. The remedy is to set them right as to facts, pardon & pacify them**.** What signify a few lives lost in a century or two? The tree of liberty must be refreshed from time to time with the blood of patriots & tyrants. It is it's natural manure.

My question is, who is Jefferson referring to when he says "The remedy is to set **them** right as to facts..."

Because right before the previous sentence "Let **them** take arms." is referring to the rebels during Shays Rebellion, so it is assumed the **"them"** in the second sentence would also be the rebels, but if that is the case, would it not be contradicting the whole letter up to this point if **them** was referring to the same people who Jefferson  just said periodic rebellion is necessary?

Is the **them** in the second sentence referring to the governing body at the time and NOT the rebels?

Answer (score 2):

> The part which is wrong will be discontented in proportion to the importance of the facts they misconceive. . . .  The remedy is to set them right as to facts, pardon & pacify them.

Those who are discontented will take up arms; the response of civil society is to set them right as to the facts, then pardon and pacify those whose contentment is newly restored.

Comment: Your are connecting two sentences together which are clearly so separated. Why would he suggest a "remedy" when he so clearly said that rebellion is necessary?

Comment: @Levydee His ideal rebellion isn't a permanent thing, but something that happens and then we move on from. It's not necessary for the rebels to win. (they didn't in the the events he's referring to) Though I guess if they did win they would be the ones passing out facts, pardons and pacification.